# How can a domain be registered but still get a DNS error?

Tags: domains, dns

When attempting to go to cloudfront.net, my browser reports a DNS error. However, when doing a whois on the domain, it reports that the domain has been registered since 2008.

I'm wondering how can the domain be registered but not work?

Answer (score 4):

Just because I own a domain, doesn't mean it has to be in DNS.  Even if nameservers are assigned, if the host hasn't created a zone file, the internet can't see the domain.

The reason for  doing this might be to stop squatting, but if it were me, I would redirect the domain to my primary domain.

Answer (score 3):

A domain name can be used for other things than web browsing. This domain name has NS records but `www.cloudfront.net` has no A record, hence the error with your browser. If you search online you will see that this domain name is used in hostnames such as `d1ge9gepfw1oo6.cloudfront.net`.

It is Amazon CDN offering, see https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/details/